# 500 Internal Server Error on Payza IPN Handler

Tags: codeigniter, curl, paypal-ipn

I am migrating an app from PayPal to Payza (formerly AlertPay). When I run the code directly from the browser to test the token handling it shows up in the logs and I get a proper response: token=47TXhMVgdPrmV3n5aauIZ5CC0MrytYXWjID81pjVnQsEhkSUklPXT3clXZ4SFUFOL5WqepRUpBz5SKomoyPuDw==& INVALID TOKEN.   When I run the full IPN response directly in the browser I get a fail but no visible errors.

But when I generate a transaction or resend an IPN from Payza it is not showing up in the log and I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I have turned on allow Query Strings in the CI config file.

```
class PayzaIPN {  
function validate_ipn($payzaIPN ='',$logId = null)  {

define("IPN_V2_HANDLER", "https://secure.payza.com/ipn2.ashx");
define("TOKEN_IDENTIFIER", "token=");
$_POST['token'] = ''; 

$token = urlencode($_POST['token']);

$token = TOKEN_IDENTIFIER.$payzaIPN;



$response = '';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, IPN_V2_HANDLER);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if(strlen($response) > 0)
```

Comment: What does your php error log say?

Comment: Thanks for looking at the question Brendan. The Apache domain logs are empty.  The CI application log for the script also has no entries when called from the processor.  If called directly from the browser it logs the appropriate errors for an invalid transaction. I have asked the server admin to look into the server logging.

Comment: It looks as though the code you provided is only partial? Can you confirm that there are closing brackets for the function and the class? I don't want to go based on assumptions.

Comment: yes, the function is properly closed.  I have gotten a bit more insight on the issue(s) and its not pretty.  First, the application is set not to allow QueryStrings and if I set it to allow QueryStrings then some of the other existing functionality fails. And then to make matters even more challenging, the payment service doesn't support custom merchant variables so passing the CSRF token is a problem.

Comment: Since the issue has changed from internal server error I reposted this as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465102/csrf-workaround-for-ipn-via-form-method-post-quandry